# Which one is better , Link-list or Tree, Memory-wise (RAM) ..?

Tags: data-structures

Which one is better , Link-list or Tree, Memory-wise (RAM) ..?

Link-list is a linear structure. Or Tree is Leveled Structure( child-nodes) . 
Which one is better memory-wise. Not searching-wise.

Comment: The most efficient structure, if you don't care about access but only about memory usage, is to throw everything away. Uses zero memory. Access *has* to be a consideration.

Comment: Throw everything away ? i could not be understand properly your answer ?

Comment: I'm saying that if you don't care, at all, about access to this data, then *not storing* the data is the obviously "best" storage structure - it uses zero memory, but has the downside that you can never access the data at all. But according to your question, access isn't important, so that's all right.

Comment: why not storing the data ?  ..  i asked memory-wise, mean we are storing something in it.  for example, we are strong some record of students. 
which one will be the better?

Answer (score 1):

Besides Damien's witty comment : what sort of tree ? Binary ? Red/black ? Ternary ? With a linked-list of children for each node ? Nodes referencing their parent or not ?

Once you chose your data structure, you just look at the overhead for each node. For instance, a singly linked list node's overhead is one pointer to the next element. A simple binary tree node's overhead typically will be two pointers : one two each child. So there you go, simple as that. That particular list would have twice less overhead than that particular tree, only considering the data structure itself.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing a linked-list and a tree, memory rarely is to consider because the purposes of these 2 data structures are completely different. In terms of memory linked list can be compared to a vector (an array): because a vector stores items on adjacent memory, it does not need a pointer along with each item so a vector/array consumes less memory. A tree needs a vector of children in each node, while each item in this vector is a pointer to a child node. So a tree consumes at least as much memory as a linked-list because for each node except the root a pointer to that node is stored in its parent.

Comment: Very good , and clear answer, thank you , I was searching actually , you told.  Impressive.   I was thinking on the same point of view.